# How to put defer attribute for facebook <noscript> tag

Tags: javascript, html, seo, noscript

I don't want to load my facebook script tag before the page gets loaded for improving my page speed and I don't know how to put a defer tag for it,

For regular JS files I do like this

```
<script src="demo_defer.js" defer></script>
```

I am not sure how to put it for a noscript tag

```
 <noscript><img height="1" width="1"  class="displaynone" alt="facebook" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=sss3933884uej&ev=PageView&noscript=1"></noscript>
 <noscript><img src="https://d5nxst8fruw4z.cloudfront.net/atdddddrk.gif?account=d3d3dddffedFLssssds1em" alt="facebook" class="displaynone" height="1" width="1"/></noscript>
```

Comment: You cannot. But if Script is active, the noscript is ignored since that is what it is supposed to be

Comment: Hi mplungjan,I am trying to increase my mobile speed(SEO) i did it for desktop after putting the defer attribute but its not happening for mobile.

Comment: Can you please see my question    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950270/how-to-eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-error-for-mobile/41950406?noredirect=1#comment71080893_41950406

Answer (score 1):

Your best and only option is to put that `noscript` tag at the end of your page (in the `body` section). It will be processed/displayed last and only if JS is not enabled.